# How do I use a dynamic URL that won't redirect to error page when the URL doesn't match any of the routes I've declared? - react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, url-parameters

I am creating a project with react-router-dom where I want the URL to hold an id. The id will be used to fetch information about the item with that id from a database and render it on the page. I've already successfully implemented data loading based on the id in the url.

My issue is that react-router-dom seems to interpret the url with the id as an unknown route and redirects it to my error page.

This is how my routes are set up:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
      { path: "progress", element: <Progress /> },
      { path: "logworkout", element: <LogWorkout /> },
      {
        path: "programs",
        element: <Programs />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Navigate to="myprograms" replace /> },
          { path: "discover", element: <DiscoverPrograms /> },
          {
            path: "myprograms",
            element: <MyPrograms />,
            children: [
              {
                path: ":programID",
                element: <ProgramView />,
                loader: programViewLoader,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      { path: "product", element: <Product /> },
      { path: "contact", element: <Contact /> },
    ],
  },
]);
```

I basically want /programs/myprograms/:programID to render instead of the error page. I think I followed the tutorial on react-router-dom's documentation pretty well and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Edit: Only `<Programs/>` in `/programs` renders an `Outlet`

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Programs = () => {
  return (
    <div className="grid overflow-hidden" style={{gridTemplateColumns: "auto 1fr"}}>
      <SideBar />
      <div className="overflow-auto">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Programs;
```

Edit: The issue isn't about the dynamic route but about the loader function I'm using for `<ProgramView/>`. Apparently, I'm not returning a value in the loader.

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { refreshToken } from "../../../../util/auth";

export const programViewLoader = ({ params }) => {
  refreshToken()
    .then((refresh) => {
      return fetch("http://localhost:5000/program/load-program", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("accessToken")}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          programID: params.programID,
        }),
      });
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((data) => {
          throw { error: data.error, status: response.status };
        });
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.program);
      return data.program;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return { error: "An error occurred while loading the program." };
    });
};
```

However the `console.log()` always prints something so I'm not sure how it isn't returning anything

Comment: Do all the routed components in that path chain (*e.g. `Programs` and `MyPrograms`*) render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render their `element` content into? Can you [edit] to include these components for a more complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only `<Programs />` in `"/programs"` renders an `Outlet`

This allows only the ***immediately*** nested routes to be rendered into the parent route component's `Outlet`, e.g:

- `Navigate`  on the `"/programs"` index route
- `DiscoverPrograms` on `"/programs/discover"`
- `MyPrograms` on `"/programs/myprograms"`

Any of these components would need to, yet again, render another `Outlet` of their own for any nested routes they may be rendering.

```
const MyPrograms = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...

    <Outlet />

    ...
  );
};
```

Now `ProgramView` should be renderable via `MyPrograms`' `Outlet` via `Programs`' `Outlet` on `"/programs/myprograms/:programID"`.

The `programViewLoader` isn't returning a value. The `refreshToken` function returns a Promise chain, but then you need to actually return the result of the Promise chain from the loader function.

```js
export const programViewLoader = ({ params }) => {
  return refreshToken() // <-- return Promise chain!
    .then((refresh) => {
      return fetch("http://localhost:5000/program/load-program", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("accessToken")}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          programID: params.programID,
        }),
      });
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((data) => {
          throw { error: data.error, status: response.status };
        });
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.program);
      return data.program;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return { error: "An error occurred while loading the program." };
    });
};
```

Comment: I added the ``Outlet`` but it still redirected me to an error page. After getting rid of my custom error page, ``react-router-dom``'s error page said my loader function wasn't returning a value which is a completely different issue. Thanks for pointing out the  ``Outlet`` problem to me! Makes sense

Comment: @JiaHuang You should return the Promise chain that `refreshToken` starts.

Comment: @JiaHuang Welcome, glad to help. Yeah, those can sometimes be tricky to see, especially when looking at your own code. Cheers and good luck!